# Custom Fragment animation without xml

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, fragment, objectanimator

I'm trying to animate fragment transition and it works when I use objectAnimator in xml in `setCustomAnimations`, but I need to set the start and end position at runtime so after some searching I found I can override `onCreateAnimator` and return a custom animator.

I'm probably missing something but what to set as the target of the animator?

```
@Override
public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(???, "y", 2392.0f, 2300.0f);
    return animator;
}
```

I saw examples that set it like this

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "y", 2392.0f, 2300.0f);
```

but then I get a message that there is no setY method (which makes sense since it's looking for it in the fragment)

I Tried setting the `View` inflated in `onCreateView` as the target but that didn't help.

The [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateAnimator(int,%20boolean,%20int)) are a bit lacking regarding this method so any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem, and I thought, why not try with `null`? Did not seem like a brilliant idea, but it worked like a charm!

```
@Override
public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(null, "y", 2392.0f, 2300.0f);
}
```